# React/Redux async issue hides mapStateToProps data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider my component method

```
clickRunButton() {
    this.props.resetTaskBatch({
        tasks: threeSampleTasks,
        busy: true
    });

    // In this method this.props.taskBatch.tasks should have three items
    this.performTasks(); 
}
```

The problem is this.props.taskBatch is empty in performTasks method. Testing with a setTimeout gives interesting results. Is there some async stuff I need to understand about react/redux?

```
clickRunButton() {
    this.props.resetTaskBatch({
        tasks: threeSampleTasks,
        busy: true
    });

    // zero objects in tasks key
    console.log(this.props.taskBatch);

    // three objects in task key after 100 ms!!
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(this.props.taskBatch); }.bind(this), 100);

    // but I need them right away here        
    this.performTasks(); 
}
```

How can I sort this out?
Thanks!

---

UPDATE
Here is the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    tasks: [],
    busy: false
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TASK_BATCH_RESET':
            var taskBatch = Object.assign({}, action.payload);
            return taskBatch;
            break;        
        case 'TASK_BATCH_UPDATED':
            var taskBatch = Object.assign({}, action.payload);
            return taskBatch;
            break;
        default:
            return state;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `this.props.resetTaskBatch`?

Comment: What does `resetTaskBatch` look like? There must be some async code inside of it.

Comment: If it's dispatching to the store, then it depends how everything is wired out. 
If your component is a subscriber to redux (wired up with `connect` from react-redux for instance) then the result of dispatching is not immediately available and will be made available by the store from the subscription you set up earlier.

Without more code on your particular setup with redux it's difficult to tell.

Comment: I think the problem you're experiencing is that the component updating is an async operation. The entire `clickRunButton` method will be executed with the current props/state, before the component receives new props. You need to run `this.performTasks()` after the component has received new props.

Comment: Thanks, please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the redux store happens asynchronously just like setState and hence calling this.performTasks just after dispatching an action to update the store won't have the right data,

You have two options, either return a promise from the dispatched action or else take the action in `componentDidUpdate` function (as per the laster RFC to React, componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated from version 17 onwards and renamed to `UNSAFE_ComponentWillReceiveProps`) and hence it is encouraged to take the necessary action in componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(!_.isEqual(this.props.taskBatch.tasks, prevProps.taskBatch.tasks) {
        this.performTasks(); 
   }
}
```

or

```
  this.props.resetTaskBatch({
        tasks: threeSampleTasks,
        busy: true
    }).then(() => {
          this.performTasks(); 
   });
```

Comment: calling `store.dispach` is not an async operation, what do you mean by "updating the redux store is an async operation" ?

Comment: Thanks, could you also help me with the syntax for the promise?

Comment: @adz5A, sorry for being unclear, what I meant was that store updates happen asynchronously

Comment: You can make use of redux-thunk middleware. Check this documentation https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: imo, this is still not true. React updates "can" happen asynchronously but store dispatches do not. However  a particular dispatch can trigger other asynchronous task inside a middleware or a thunk for instance. This is very important and allows you to observe the evolution of your store and determine if you need to update your UI or not.

Calls to `setState` however will trigger a render, but then again it may or may not be asynchronous, it's simply enqueued: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: I would not advise reference to `this` in promise callbacks: your component might unmount before it is resolved and then your app might blow up ("calling setState on unmounted component")